# Can't declare class constant nor property variable

Tags: php, class, properties, constants, declaration

```
class Model {

  public $DATABASE_NAME = 'dealer-kunde-skuska';

       // OR

  const DATABASE_NAME = 'dealer-kunde-skuska';

}
```

None of above declarations works. It returns error:

> Parse error: parse error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in ... on line 5

What could be wrong?

Comment: is this really the original code?

Comment: works for me, just tested

Comment: Is this all of the code? Are there namespace declarations or anything else above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public` and `const` are only available as of PHP 5.  `var` is used in PHP 4.

> Support for PHP 4 has been discontinued since 2007-12-31. Please consider upgrading to PHP 5.

Upgrade maybe?  PHP 5 has been around for 11 years and PHP 4 discontinued for 7.